# Create order after successful charge using stripe checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I am using stripe checkout for my payment solution within and e-commerce app. I want to create an order after a successful charge.

At the moment once payment is successful I just change a "success" boolean attribute on the current cart before destroying the cart. I will like to create an order instead so the cart object does not have to deal with this extra responsibility.

My problem is that I do not know where to tell my controller to create an order and how to pass data from the current cart to the order object.

Here is the charges controller setup

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

def new
    @user = current_user
    @cart = current_cart
    @amount = @cart.total_price
end

def create

  @amount = @cart.total_price

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => @user.email,
    :card  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => @user.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'usd'
  )

      # this changes the status of the current cart to success 
  @cart.update_status(current_cart)
  session[:cart_id] = nil
  redirect_to current_user, notice: 'You placed an order!'

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to charges_path
  end    

end
```

Comment: have you figured this out? Please update...

Comment: sure, just create the Order object just before the rescue clause. You can create the Order directly in your controller but it is a lot cleaner to create a class method in your Order model to handle this. Let me know if this helps you out.

Comment: @Joshua I actually do wish you posted your answer would have helped me right now. Post if you still can and mark as answered to help not just me but future people who stumble on your question.

Comment: Ok, will answer question. But can you let me know what exactly you are struggling with ? unless it is the exact same problem